# Fill a vector with references to another vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector of Structs that represent points (allPoints). This vector contains the entire collection of points on a given plane (in this example it contains four points). Each struct contains a pair of integers representing a point, a flag, as well as another vector of points which contains every other point on the plane.

What I want to do is select a point from the preference list of a point, change its flag, and have this change apply to the point in the allPoints vector. I imagine I need a vector of references or something similar. Here is an example of what I am talking about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    pair<int,int> p;
    vector<Point> prefs;
    bool flag = true;
};

void fillVectors(vector<Point> & allPoints);
void printState(vector<Point> & allPoints);

int main()
{
    vector<Point> allPoints; 

    fillVectors(allPoints);
    printState(allPoints);

    // I want to go into the preference list of any given point, select a point, and change its flag. This change
    // should be reflected in the allPoints vector, not just the preferences vector

    allPoints[0].prefs[2].flag = false;

    printState(allPoints);

    // The flags have not changed. If I searh for the point in allPoints, then change the flag, it will change
    for(Point p : allPoints)
    {
        if(p.p == allPoints[0].prefs[2].p) allPoints[0].flag = false;


    }
    printState(allPoints);
}

void fillVectors(vector<Point> & allPoints)
{  

  pair<int,int> p1 = make_pair(0,0);
  pair<int,int> p2 = make_pair(5,0);
  pair<int,int> p3 = make_pair(3,7);
  pair<int,int> p4 = make_pair(2,9);
  vector<pair<int,int>> coords = {p1, p2, p3, p4};

    for(int i = 0; i < coords.size(); i++)
    {
        Point newPoint;        
        newPoint.p = coords[i];
        allPoints.push_back(newPoint);
    }

    // Fill the preference lists with every other point (in no particular order)
    for(int i = 0; i < allPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < allPoints.size(); j++)
        {
            if(i == j) continue; // Do not put a point in its own preference list
            allPoints[i].prefs.push_back(allPoints[j]);
        }

    }
}

void printState(vector<Point> & allPoints)
{        
    cout << "Contents of all points:\n";

    for(Point p : allPoints)
        cout << "point: (" << p.p.first << "," << p.p.second << ")" << "  Flagged? -> " << p.flag << "\n";
    cout << "~\nContents of each preference vector:\n";

    for(Point p : allPoints)
    {
        cout << "point: (" << p.p.first << "," << p.p.second << ")\tprefs: ";
        for(Point q : p.prefs)
            cout << "(" << q.p.first << "," << q.p.second << "), ";
       cout << "\n";

    }
     cout << "--------------------\n";
}
```

Here, I have allPoints which holds four pairs. The print state function prints every point from the all points along with its flag, then the preference list of each point. What I need is for the prefs vector in each point to hold *references* to that point object in the allPoints vector. Instead, it just seems to be making a copy.

I want do to this so that I can change point flags in O(1) time, rather than the O(n) time it takes to get the point from the preferences, then search for it in allPoints and change it

Comment: Make your Allpoints to hold vector of Points pointer something like `vector<Point *>` And make copy constructor function private in your Point Class implementation

Comment: The problem with a vector of pointers is because as soon as the enclosing vector gets reallocated, all these inner pointers become utterly and completely worthless.

Comment: This may be useful: [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

If the only part of state which you want to be shared is `flag` and if you do not plan to change value of `Point::p` member once object created, you can replace `bool flag` with `std::shared_ptr<bool> flag` and when copies are created - `shared_ptr` will be copied and it will hold the value shared between objects.

```
struct Point
{
    Point(const std::pair<int,int>& value)
        : p(value)
    {}

    Point(const Point&) = default;
    Point& operator = (const Point&) = default;

    const std::pair<int,int> p;
    vector<Point> prefs;
    std::shared_ptr<bool> flag = std::make_shared<bool>(true);
};
```

Then if you will do:

```
Point pt1({1,2});
auto pt2 = pt1;

std::cout << *pt2.flag << " ";
*pt1.flag = false;
std::cout << *pt2.flag << " ";
```

the output will be "1 0" since `pt1` and `pt2` objects share same `bool`.

Note: if there is no `const` for `Point::p` then it's possible to change it's value after copies from object are created - in this case sharing `flag` for such objects makes no sense.

Of course, that would be easy to break given all members are public, so you'll need to access `flag` carefully. To make this code safe - encapsulation should be used.